# VBA Limit Text Length Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I had a follow up question to a question I had a few hours ago, but haven't gotten a reply back. So here I am.

The code below, how can I make it so that it only applies to a column? More specifically, E14:E1000.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In Target
        If Len(cell) > 10 Then
            MsgBox "Text length in cell """ & cell.Address(0, 0) & """ is more than 10.", vbExclamation
            Application.Undo
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: use intersect :https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/application-intersect-method-excel `If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Range("E14:E100")) Is Nothing Then dO YOUR STUFF End If`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim cell As Range
Dim testRange As Range

Set testRange = Range("e14:e1000")

If Not Intersect(Target, testRange) Is Nothing Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    For Each cell In Intersect(Target, testRange)
    If Len(cell) > 10 Then
        MsgBox "Text length in cell """ & cell.Address(0, 0) & """ is more than 10.", vbExclamation
        Application.Undo
        Exit For
    End If
    Next cell

Application.EnableEvents = True
End If

End Sub
```